# How to use Mathjax in android, offline

Tags: java, android, html, mathjax

I saw this post

http://cs.jsu.edu/wordpress/?p=498

and I tried using mathjax in offline

I just want to include this code in my html

`w.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar/", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                              +"MathJax.Hub.Config({ " 
                                +"showMathMenu: false, "
                                +"jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], " // output/SVG
                                +"extensions: ['tex2jax.js','toMathML.js'], " 
                                +"TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                                  +"'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, "
                              //+"'SVG' : { blacker: 30, "
                              // +"styles: { path: { 'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges' } } } "
                              +"});</script>"
                              +"<script type='text/javascript' "
                              +"src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
                              +"></script>"
                              +"<script type='text/javascript'>getLiteralMML = function() {"
                              +"math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];"
                              // below, toMathML() rerurns literal MathML string
                              +"mml=math.root.toMathML(''); return mml;"
                              +"}; getEscapedMML = function() {"
                              +"math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];"
                              // below, toMathMLquote() applies &-escaping to MathML string input
                              +"mml=math.root.toMathMLquote(getLiteralMML()); return mml;}"
                              +"</script>"
                              +"<span id='math'></span><pre><span id='mmlout'></span></pre>","text/html","utf-8","");`

i tried many times but didn't work.

i tried this html

```
<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>
                          MathJax.Hub.Config({ 
                            showMathMenu: false, 
                            jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'],  // output/SVG
                            extensions: ['tex2jax.js','toMathML.js'], 
                            TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',
                              'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] }, "
                          'SVG' : { blacker: 30, 
                          styles: { path: { 'shape-rendering': 'crispEdges' } } } 
                          });</script>
                          <script type='text/javascript' 
                          src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'
                          ></script>"
                          <script type='text/javascript'>getLiteralMML = function() {
                          math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];
                          // below, toMathML() rerurns literal MathML string
                          mml=math.root.toMathML(''); return mml;
                          }; getEscapedMML = function() {
                          math=MathJax.Hub.getAllJax('math')[0];

                          mml=math.root.toMathMLquote(getLiteralMML()); return mml;}
                          </script>
                          <span id='math'></span><pre><span id='mmlout'></span></pre>
```

I am not good at html help me please

Comment: Not an answer but this app's source code might give you some insight https://github.com/xcaspad/android_xcaspad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
           webview.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
        }
    });
```

and

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar",
            "<html><head>" +
                    " <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=yes\" />" +
                    "</head>" +
                    "" +
                    "<body style=\"font-size:18px\" >" +
                    message+
                    "</br> " +
                    "<script type=\"text/x-mathjax-config\">" +
                    "  MathJax.Hub.Config({\n" +
                    "  CommonHTML: { linebreaks: { automatic: true },EqnChunk:(MathJax.Hub.Browser.isMobile?10:50) },displayAlign: \"left\",\n" +
                    "  \"HTML-CSS\": { linebreaks: { automatic: true } ," +
                    "\n" +
                    "    preferredFont: \"STIX\"}," +
                    "extensions: [\"tex2jax.js\"],messageStyle:\"none\"," +
                    "jax: [\"input/TeX\", \"input/MathML\",\"output/HTML-CSS\"]," +
                    "tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\\\(','\\\\)']]}" +
                    "});" +
                    "</script>" +
                    "<script type=\"text/javascript\" async src=\"file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML\"></script>" +
                    "" +
                    "</body>" +
                    "</html>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
```

Comment: You should add a short explanation of your answer.

Comment: @DovBenyominSohacheski Well I have not much knowledge about HTML but I spent a lot of time finding for the solution and this code worked well with the latest Offline library of **MathJax**.

Answer (score 0):

Wait for page to load before setting text.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

                   // do your stuff here
                   question_webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('mmlout').innerHTML='';");
                   question_webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\\\["
                   +text.getText()+"\\\\]';");
                   question_webview.loadUrl("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);");
                   //question_webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('mmlout').style.fontSize='200%'");
                   //question_webview.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('math').style.fontSize='200%'");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but I can't solve the problem.